# Wrapping Windows Thread API

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

My goal is to wrap Windows Thread API with my own struct.

Specifically, I want to use `function_impl()` as a wrapper for `function()` and have each instance of `Thread` create a Windows thread with it's own `function()`.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <windows.h>

struct Thread {
    std::function<void()> function;
    HANDLE win_thread;

    Thread(std::function<void()>);
    ~Thread();

    DWORD WINAPI function_impl(LPVOID lpParam) { function(); return 0; }
};

Thread::Thread(std::function<void()> _function)
    : function(_function)
{
    win_thread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, Thread::function_impl, nullptr, CREATE_SUSPENDED, nullptr);
}

Thread::~Thread()
{
    TerminateThread(win_thread, 0);
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't compile.

Both this `Thread::function_impl` and `&Thread::function_impl` return `"DWORD (__stdcall Thread::*)(LPVOID lpParam)" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE"`.

`this->function_impl` returns `'Thread::function_impl': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`.

`&this->function_impl` returns `'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression`.

As far as I understand, the problem is that `function_impl()` needs to be static for this to work, but why and is there a way around it?

Comment: Why not use `std::thread` ?

Comment: Since you're using `functional` can we safely assume you are avoiding `std::thread` for fun or educational purposes?

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, I need to use Windows API.

Comment: But that is what `std::thread` must do - so the wrapper is already written

Comment: Member functions have different rules from free functions. For example, how do you get `this` in? Here's a good rundown: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: Old New Thing - __Windows started picking up the really big pieces of TerminateThread garbage on the sidewalk, but it’s still garbage on the sidewalk__  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811

Comment: C++20 coroutines have been supported by Visual Studio since Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. One specific use case for coroutines is to enable asynchronous operations. A well-designed implementations makes even `std::thread` look dated. If you need to continue the approach you described, don't forget that you are crossing language boundaries. All your C++ exceptions leak into a C interface that doesn't know what to do with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand, the problem is that `function_impl()` needs to be `static` for this to work

In your example, yes.

> but why

When `function_impl()` is a class method without `static`, it will have a hidden `this` parameter that affects its signature, making it incompatible with what `CreateThread()` is expecting.

> is there a way around it?

When `function_impl()` is a class method, declaring it as `static` is the correct way.  Use the `lpParameter` parameter of `CreateThread()` to pass in the `this` pointer of the `Thread` object, eg:

```cpp
struct Thread {
    std::function<void()> function;
    HANDLE win_thread;

    Thread(std::function<void()>);
    ~Thread();

    static DWORD WINAPI function_impl(LPVOID lpParam);
};
```

```cpp
Thread::Thread(std::function<void()> _function)
    : function(_function)
{
    win_thread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, &Thread::function_impl, this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, nullptr);
}

DWORD WINAPI Thread::function_impl(LPVOID lpParam) {
    static_cast<Thread*>(lpParam)->function();
    return 0;
}

...
```

The alternative is to make `function_impl()` be a free-standing function instead, not a class method, eg:

```cpp
struct Thread {
    std::function<void()> function;
    HANDLE win_thread;

    Thread(std::function<void()>);
    ~Thread();
};
```

```cpp
static DWORD WINAPI function_impl(LPVOID lpParam) {
    static_cast<Thread*>(lpParam)->function();
    return 0;
}

Thread::Thread(std::function<void()> _function)
    : function(_function)
{
    win_thread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, &Thread::function_impl, this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, nullptr);
}

...
```

Or, you can use a *non-capturing* lambda instead:

```cpp
struct Thread {
    std::function<void()> function;
    HANDLE win_thread;

    Thread(std::function<void()>);
    ~Thread();
};
```

```cpp
Thread::Thread(std::function<void()> _function)
    : function(_function)
{
    win_thread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0,
        [](LPVOID lpParam){
            static_cast<Thread*>(lpParam)->function();
            return 0;
        },
        this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, nullptr);
}

...
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++, member functions are not regular functions. As you can see they always know which object they are working on through a specific `this` pointer.

Win32 is a C API and it expects a regular function pointer. If you make your member function `static`, then it's a regular function the C API can utilize. But in that case, how do you use non-static member variables from the object? The solution is to pass `this` pointer as `lpThreadParameter` to this static function and use it to access non-static member variables. Here is my implementation.

```cpp
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define NOMINMAX
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

struct Thread
{
  private:
    std::function<void()> m_func;
    HANDLE m_thread;

    static DWORD WINAPI thread_main(LPVOID lpThreadParameter) noexcept
    {
        try
        {
            static_cast<Thread *>(lpThreadParameter)->m_func();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

  public:
    Thread(std::function<void()> func)
        : m_func(std::move(func))
        , m_thread(CreateThread(nullptr, 0, thread_main, this, 0, nullptr))
    {
        if (!m_thread)
            throw std::runtime_error("Thread creation failed");
    }

    Thread(Thread const &) = delete;
    Thread &operator=(Thread const &) = delete;

    ~Thread()
    {
        if (m_thread)
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(m_thread, INFINITE);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Thread th([] { 
        std::printf("Thread id: %lu\n", (unsigned long)GetCurrentThreadId()); 
    });
}
```